# MochaUI window z-index

Tags: javascript, activex, mocha.js

I'm working with MochaUI windows, for example:

```
new MUI.Window({
    id: 'PanelId',
    loadMethod: 'html',
    contentURL: 'pages/Panel.html',
    closeAfter: 0,
    type: 'notification',
    addClass: 'notification',
    content: 'Notification Window',
    width: 350,
    height: 40,
    y: 150,
    x: 100,
    padding: { top: 10, right: 12, bottom: 10, left: 12 },
    shadowBlur: 5
});
```

My problem is that I'm trying to open the window above a control that runs an ActiveX which renders video.
I'm not able to get the window on top of the video.
The window is above all other controls (which one of them holds the ActiveX) but the part of the MochaUI window which is on top of the video, is always "cropped".

Any ideas?

(the black area is part of the video!)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to fix the problem.
I'm setting my load type to iFrame instead of html:

```
new MUI.Window({
        id: 'MyWindow',
        loadMethod: 'iframe',
```

Now I have flickering but that's a different problem.